# Ignore nil elements when sorting

Tags: sorting, go, slice

For sorting such struct I implemented three methods:

```
type Event struct {
    timeEnd interface{}
    size float64
}

func (s ByTime) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}
func (s ByTime) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}
```

Sometimes not all `Events.timeEnd` are initialized and I want to put such `Event`s into the back of slice and sorting them by `size` field.

```
func (s ByTime) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if s[i].timeEnd == nil || s[j].timeEnd == nil{
        return s[i].size < s[j].size
    }else {
        return s[i].timeEnd.(float64) < s[j].timeEnd.(float64)
    }
}

 a, b, c, d := Event{timeEnd:12.}, Event{timeEnd:nil, size:-10}, Event{timeEnd:56.}, Event{timeEnd:nil, size:2}
 queue := []*Event{}
 queue = append(queue, &a, &b, &c, &d)
```

But as result I have:

```
[<nil> 12 56 <nil>]
```

While expecting `[12 56 <nil> <nil>]`
How to implement it correctly?

Here example in https://play.golang.org/p/FWU98npGtbU

Comment: size:2 of `d` is greater than size:0 of `a` and `c`. So you get `b,a,c,d` after sorting.

Comment: If you always want nil at the end, then you have to always compare them as greater than those that aren't nil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Less`, you don't want to compare the `size`s unless *both* `timeEnd`s are `nil` and then you'd need to handle the "only one `timeEnd` is `nil`" cases separately. So you have four cases to consider not two:

```
func (s ByTime) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if s[i].timeEnd == nil && s[j].timeEnd == nil {
        return s[i].size < s[j].size
    } else if s[i].timeEnd == nil {
        return false
    } else if s[j].timeEnd == nil {
        return true
    } else {
        return s[i].timeEnd.(float64) < s[j].timeEnd.(float64)
    }
}
```